# regex split filename vba

Tags: regex, vba

i have several files which have two types of filenames

1. "c:\path\filename [some text].pdf" or
2. "c:\path\filename.pdf"

i want to split the files as follows:

- Group 1: c:\path\
- Group 2: filename
- Group 3: [123] (or empty)
- Group 4: pdf

this regex-pattern works for file-type 2 (without brackets) but not for filetype 1.:

```
^(.*\\)(.*)s*?(\[.*\]).*?([a-z]*)$
```

why doesnt it work for filetype 2? what pattern can i use, that matches both filename-types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(.*\\)(.*?)(?:\s*(\[.*\]))?\.([a-zA-Z]*)$
            ^^^           ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/haHFug/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*\\)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars, as many as possible
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\s*(\[.*\]))?` - an optional group that matches

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(\[.*\])` - Group 3: a `[`, any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars, as many as possible and a `]`
- `\.` - a `.`
- `([a-zA-Z]*)` - Group 4: 0+ letters (or, just use `[^.]*` to match any chars other than `.`)
- `$` - end of string.